# Unmarshaling XML: use different target type based on an attribute value

Tags: go

I want to use a different type to unmarshal the XML content of a child node based on its parent's name attribute.

In the following example I have 2 children nodes with attributes "apple" and "peach".  I would like to use type `Apple` when the attribute is `"apple"` and `Peach` when it's `"peach"`.  Basically `Apple` and `Peach` have very different structures, so that's the scenario.  How would I accomplish that or what would be the suggested approach?

Here is the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4uhhSkN6UQc) with a basic setup to the problem.

```xml
<element>
    <node name="apple">
        <apple>
            <color>red<color>
        </apple>
    </node>
    <node name="peach"> 
        <peach>
            <size>medium</size>
        </peach>
    </node>
</element>
```

```golang
var x = `...` // xml
type Element struct {
    Nodes []struct{
        Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
    } `xml:"node"`
    Apple Apple
    Peach Peach
}
type Apple struct { // use this struct if name is "apple"
    Color string 
} 
type Peach struct { // use this struct if name is "peach"
    Size string
}
func main() {
    e := Element{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &e)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
    fmt.Println(e.Apple.Color)
    fmt.Println(e.Peach.Size
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/GOqySHhNMbJ

Comment: Basically: You cannot do this. You will either have to unmarshal in steps or write your on Unmarshaler.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the example using `d.Token()`!

Comment: @believesInSanta no problem, although I realize that for this example case it's a bit overkill since all you need are [tags](https://play.golang.com/p/fU3PPqtbtEJ) to get the same result. It would make more sense if your go structs would look more like this: https://play.golang.com/p/Ds5VEcVSXHE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate on the nodes of your `Element` type and create the `Apple` and `Peach` structures as you go, by switching on their `Name` attribute:

```golang
    for _, element := range e.Nodes {
        switch element.Name {
        case "apple":
            apples = append(apples, Apple{})
        case "peach":
            peaches = append(peaches, Peach{})
        }
    }
```

[Here is a playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/TY8MxRNstiQ).

Another, more complex solution (but also more elegant and practical) would be to implement your own `UnmarshalXML` method on your `Element` type, which would directly populate it with the proper types:

```golang
type Apple struct {
    Color string
}
type Peach struct {
    Size string
}

type Fruits struct {
    Apples  []Apple
    Peaches []Peach
}

type Element struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"element"`
    Nodes   []struct {
        Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
        Apple struct {
            Color string `xml:"color"`
        } `xml:"apple"`
        Peach struct {
            Size string `xml:"size"`
        } `xml:"peach"`
    } `xml:"node"`
}

func (f *Fruits) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var element Element
    d.DecodeElement(&element, &start)

    for _, el := range element.Nodes {
        switch el.Name {
        case "apple":
            f.Apples = append(f.Apples, Apple{
                Color: el.Apple.Color,
            })
        case "peach":
            f.Peaches = append(f.Peaches, Peach{
                Size: el.Peach.Size,
            })
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    f := Fruits{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Apples:", f.Apples)
    fmt.Println("Peaches", f.Peaches)
}
```

[Here is a playground link for this second solution](https://goplay.space/#F5TWPwCoJmS)

Result:

> ```
> Apples: [{red}]
> Peaches [{medium}]
> ```

Comment: You would have to unmarshal multiple times though.  For illustration, suppose `Apple` has "Color" element, and "Peach" has a "Size" element.  Editing post now.

Comment: Check the alternative solution I'm proposing. You would just need to implement the logic in the `Fruit` type's unmarshal function, and to call `xml.Unmarshal` on the fruits type once.

Comment: I see how you're handling the parsing within the interface method, but here you're just appending Apple's and Peach'es, how would you unmarshal the respective data into each Apple and Peach?

Comment: Done. Let me know if that answers your question :)

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Thanks :)